# Using encoding.com golang wrapper

Tags: api, go, video

I'm rather new to both golang and encoding.com and I'm trying to use [the encoding.com API wrapper](https://github.com/nytimes/encoding-wrapper) to transcode a simple video file, but I'm rather confused by the format to use.

When looking at the tests I can see how to call the `AddMedia` function (https://github.com/nytimes/encoding-wrapper/blob/master/encodingcom/media_test.go#L9-L39) but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

```
package main

import ("github.com/NYTimes/encoding-wrapper/encodingcom")

func main() {
  client, err := encodingcom.NewClient("https://manage.encoding.com", "123", "key")

  format := encodingcom.Format{
      Output:       []string{"https://key:secret@bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/aladin.ogg"},
      VideoCodec:   "libtheora",
      AudioCodec:   "libvorbis",
      Bitrate:      "400k",
      AudioBitrate: "64k",     
  }

  addMediaResponse, err := client.AddMedia([]string{"https://samples.mplayerhq.hu/h264/Aladin.mpg"},
        []encodingcom.Format{format}, "us-east-1")
  }
}
```

The error "raised" is

```
APIError.Errors.Errors0: Output format 'https://key:secret@bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/aladin.aac' is not allowed! (format #0)
APIError.Message:
```

and I really don't get it, the `Output` element in the Format looks missplaced, am I reading the test wrong? Using the API builder the format parameter should receive only the format, for example "ogg", and there's a "destination" parameter for S3. It also doesn't specify if the url must be urlencoded, but honestly I don't think so. Still keys and secrets can contain for example the char '/'

Any more experienced gopher?

Comment: 1) No, `Output` [is there](https://github.com/nytimes/encoding-wrapper/blob/f85273aef92827e577651a10d53f567f5b16e8e4/encodingcom/client.go#L155); 2) The "aac" extension looks a bit odd; since you have two codecs listed (both A fnd V), I'd expect the extension to indicate container format (like `mp4` or `avi` or `mkv`).

Comment: edited with new format. The old one was basically cut and paste from the tests

Comment: And output is there but it looks like it doesn't contain the path of the file